# How to fix Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable' error?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am creating an ionic app with Ionic 4 based on angular 6!
To set the screen orientation installed the below plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm install --save @ionic-native/screen-orientation
```

And imported in required typescript! But when i run the project i got the error below.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ionic-native/screen-orientation/index.d.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/myBake/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
[ng] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this error?

Comment: Try `npm i rxjs-compat` and run the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ionic 4 you need to install all your native plugins as beta:

`npm install --save @ionic-native/screen-orientation@beta`

Inside your code, for Angular, the import path should end with /ngx.

`import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';`

Don't install rxjs-compact.

Answer (score 0):

npm i rxjs-compat

Please add these command on your root folder